# ag-grid getRowStyle does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, css, ag-grid

I have a grid and I want the rows in this grid to be styled according to the value of one of the columns. I've done this with `getRowStyle`, where I read the value of this column and assign the background accordingly.

However, when rows get added sometimes the styles get messed up like that:

[image]

Here we can see 5 rows, 3 of them have correct styling (background color is a lighter version of the tag's color). Somehow those 2 rows preserve the background.

Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Comment: can you share what logic you are using in getRowStyle?

Comment: it's something like `getRowStyle (params) { if (params.data.tags.length) { return { background: tagColorsMap[params.data.tags[0]] } } else { return {} } }`

Comment: maybe you don't have any tags in that 2 rows so there is nothing to style?

Comment: Yeah, that's right, there are no tags, so why the background is still there?